# On ios Cancel and send button on the native mail not working.User got blocked

Tags: ios, swift3

Below is the function  for the native mail app open , Nothing happed  when cancel button clicked and Send button on native mail app is sending the mail but user also got blocked.User didn't get any action respone.

```
   @IBAction func openNativeEmail(_ sender: AnyObject){
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            debugPrint("can send mail")
        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailVC.setToRecipients(["pawanline@gmail.com"])
        mailVC.setSubject("Testing mail App features")
        mailVC.setCcRecipients(["pawan.kumar@iic.ac.in"])
        mailVC.setMessageBody("Hi,just testing ", isHTML: false)
            present(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Unable to send the mail")
        }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: The dismiss gets called?

Comment: @Yitzchak yes, It got  called when user first tap on button (openNativeEmail)

Comment: It should be called when it closes, not when it opens

Comment: Did you test on a real device or simulator?

Comment: @Yitzchak , can you please tell me ? is there any way so that I can access the action of cancel and send from the native mail  app screen?.

Comment: I am testing it on real device( iphone 6 ).

Comment: I've just compared with my working code, it's exactly the same... I'm asking again, when you tap on send or cancel in the first time, does the dismiss gets called?

Comment: No, not called when click on  send and cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing a closing bracket:

```
   @IBAction func openNativeEmail(_ sender: AnyObject){
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            debugPrint("can send mail")
        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailVC.setToRecipients(["pawanline@gmail.com"])
        mailVC.setSubject("Testing mail App features")
        mailVC.setCcRecipients(["pawan.kumar@iic.ac.in"])
        mailVC.setMessageBody("Hi,just testing ", isHTML: false)
            present(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Unable to send the mail")
        }
    } // <----- THIS WAS MISSING 

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```